# How do I use the spread operator to update a state value in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following object in my React app:

```
const processDetails = () => {
    const INIT_ERROR = {
      condition: {
        name:        "",
        description: ""
      },
      treatment: {
        name:         "",
        description:  ""
      },
    }
    
    const [error, setError] = useState(INIT_ERROR);
}
```

This is connected to a form which takes various values; on submission, it needs to be validated and the value of 'error' is updated where information is missing.

In the validation function, I have, eg:

```
if(conditionName === "")) {
      setError(...);
}
```

and I want this to set the value of error.condition.name to "Error - please enter a name for this condition".

How do I do this? I've tried:

```
setError({ ...error, condition: {...error.condition, name: "Please enter a name for this condition"} });
```

which seems to work, but then doing the same thing to update `error.condition.description`, like this:

```
setError({ ...error, condition: {...error.condition, description: "Please enter a description for this condition"} });
```

overwrites the value of `error.condition.name`.

Comment: *"which seems to work, but then doing the same thing to update error.condition.description overwrites the value of error.condition.name."* Show us that code. It's really hard to help you understand why code isn't working if you don't show us the code that doesn't work. :-)

Comment: (Side note: It's not really important, but `...` isn't an operator. Operators can't do what `...` does. It's just syntax.)

Comment: It's the same code, but with description instead of name:

Comment: setError({ ...error, condition: {...error.condition, description: "Please enter a description for this condition"} });

Comment: Hi Sharon - I've folded that comment into the question. Please hit "rollback" on the edit if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried:
>
> ```
> setError({ ...error, condition: {...error.condition, name: "Please enter a name for this condition"} });
> ```
>
> which seems to work, but then doing the same thing to update `error.condition.description` overwrites the value of `error.condition.name`.

That's how you do it, but it sounds like you're making two separate calls to `setError` using that same pattern. That won't work, because as you've found the second one will just overwrite the effect of the first. (Because `error` isn't updated right away, so when you do `...error.condition`, you're still using the old `condition.name`.) Do a single call with both updates:

```
setError({
    ...error,
    condition: {
        ...error.condition,
        name: "Please enter a name for this condition",
        description: "Updated description here"
    }
});
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> Sometimes I only want to update one of them though... basically if `conditionName` is empty, then I want to update `error.condition.name`; if `conditionDesc` is empty then I want to update `error.condition.description`. Is there a way to do one after the other?

Yes, there are a couple of ways. Probably the easiest is: Since you know that you're going to update `error` and `condition`, make a shallow copy of both, then set either `name` or `description` or both, then do the `setError`:

```
// Make a shallow copy of both `error` and `error.condition`
const updatedError = {...error, condition: {...error.condition}};
// Now it's okay to directly assign to them
if (conditionName === "") {
    updatedError.condition.name = "Please enter a name for this condition";
}
if (conditionDoc === "") {
    updatedError.condition.description = "Updated description";
}
// Now we've made all our updates, we set state
setError(updatedError);
```

You *could* combine all of that into one all-singing, all-dancing call to `setError`, but it becomes hard to read, hard to debug, and hard to maintain:

```
// I don't recommend this
setError({
    ...error,
    condition: {
        ...error.condition,
        name: conditionName === ""
            ? "Please enter a name for this condition"
            : error.condition.name,
        description: conditionDoc === ""
            ? "Updated description"
            : error.condition.description,
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Sometimes I only want to update one of them though... basically if conditionName is empty, then I want to update error.condition.name; if conditionDesc is empty then I want to update error.condition.description.  Is there a way to do one after the other?

Comment: @Sharon - Yup -- I've added to the end of the answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I made a shallow copy and that's working.